# Statsd: Which metric to use to measure data throughput

Tags: graphite, statsd

I'm fairly new to statsd, I want to measure the aggregated data volume/second that my process uses, but cannot find the correct statsd metric for it:

- increment would be good, as it gives rate, but cannot increment with a value
- gauge doesn't aggregate, just sets a value
- timers also don't feel right

So which one should I choose, and how should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a counter, you can increment it with a value. For example to increment `foo` by `3`

```
echo "foo:3|c" | nc -u -w0 127.0.0.1 8125
```

From the [data types docs](http://statsd.readthedocs.org/en/v3.1/types.html#counters):

> You can increment a counter by more than one by passing a second
>   parameter:
>
> ```
> statsd.incr('some.other.event', 10)
> ```